# Why is there always a root certificate with my computer name for server auth in my computer?

Tags: certificate, windows-11

I'm running Windows 11, when I run `sigcheck64 -tuv` or `sigcheck64 -tv` i get
[image]

I don't know why on all my computers (not networked or connected to each other), there is a root certificate with their corresponding computer name for Serve Auth in their user and machine certificate stores.
I ran that command to find any malicious root certificates but that's what shows up instead and I need to know why it's there and is it safe to keep it or should I remove it?

update:
when I run `sigcheck64 -vt` I get this result:

```
Sigcheck v2.82 - File version and signature viewer
Copyright (C) 2004-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

C:\Users\username\NTUSER.DAT:
Verified:   Error accessing file

Link date:  n/a
Publisher:  n/a
Company:    n/a
Company:    n/a
Description:    n/a
Product:    n/a
Prod version:   n/a
File version:   n/a
MachineType:    n/a
VT detection:   Unknown
VT link:    n/a

C:\Users\username\ntuser.dat.LOG1:
Verified:   Error accessing file

Link date:  n/a
Publisher:  n/a
Company:    n/a
Company:    n/a
Description:    n/a
Product:    n/a
Prod version:   n/a
File version:   n/a
MachineType:    n/a
VT detection:   Unknown
VT link:    n/a

C:\Users\username\ntuser.dat.LOG2:
Verified:   Error accessing file

Link date:  n/a
Publisher:  n/a
Company:    n/a
Company:    n/a
Description:    n/a
Product:    n/a
Prod version:   n/a
File version:   n/a
MachineType:    n/a
VT detection:   Unknown
VT link:    n/a

C:\Users\username\NTUSER.DAT{f1fc1da9-*****************0}.TM.blf:
Verified:   Error accessing file

Link date:  n/a
Publisher:  n/a
Company:    n/a
Company:    n/a
Description:    n/a
Product:    n/a
Prod version:   n/a
File version:   n/a
MachineType:    n/a
VT detection:   Unknown
VT link:    n/a
C:\Users\username\NTUSER.DAT{************************3ef760}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms:

Verified:   Error accessing file

Link date:  n/a
Publisher:  n/a
Company:    n/a
Company:    n/a
Description:    n/a
Product:    n/a
Prod version:   n/a
File version:   n/a
MachineType:    n/a
VT detection:   Unknown
VT link:    n/a
C:\Users\username\NTUSER.DAT{f1f****************ef760}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms:

Verified:   Error accessing file

Link date:  n/a
Publisher:  n/a
Company:    n/a
Company:    n/a
Description:    n/a
Product:    n/a
Prod version:   n/a
File version:   n/a
MachineType:    n/a
VT detection:   0/73
VT link:    

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/07854d2fef297a06ba81685e660c332de36d5d18d546927d30daad6d7fda1541/detection
C:\Users\username\ntuser.ini:

Verified:   Unsigned
File date:  2:42 PM 22/08/05
Publisher:  n/a
Company:    n/a
Description:    n/a
Product:    n/a
Prod version:   n/a
File version:   n/a
MachineType:    n/a
VT detection:   0/70
VT link:    

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/5ad8f52071d25165e7e68064ab194ec27a074a3846149ed0689af23e7f7f2d00/detection
```

Comment: The certificate has already expired. In fact those dates don’t even make sense. The correct command is **sigcheck64 -vt** instead of what the command you said you ran.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated my question